# Sorting an array which is split into x sorted parts

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I have been given two True/False questions regarding sorting an array. The questions are as following -

Question A

> Given an array A with 3n keys that contains three equal parts
> A[1,n], A[n+1,2n] and A[2n+1,3n], each with n keys. Each part is
> sorted. Is possible to sort the keys of A into a
> new array B in O(n) steps (worst case)?

Question B

> Given an array A with 10n keys that are comparable using a binary function that returns which element
> is bigger or if the elements are equal. The array is split into n equal parts, each
> with 10 keys. Each part is sorted. Is it possible to sort the keys of
> A into a new array B in O(n) steps (worst case)?

The solution to question A is that we can use merge() fucntion from MergeSort to sort the array.

The solution to question B is that it is not possible, as it violates the Ω(nlog(n)) lower bound for comparison based sorting algorithms

And I fail to see the difference between the two questions.. Is it because in question B we first need to apply the function? Why does it prohibits us from using merge() aswell? I don't see the logic behind the assumption that the two scenarios are different and I feel that I'm missing something important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Question A:

It is easily possible to sort it it in O(n) time.
The algorithm work as follows ->

```
1. You assign 3 pointers to the start of each sequence
2. You compare the element that pointers show to 
3. Select one you needed (smallest or greatest) and push it to new array
4. Increase the pointer you have selected and continue from the first step till all 3 of the pointers reached end of the array
```

So it is principle of the merge sort, you are right in this point.

The Question B.
Actually it the same, the difference is that the question is turned vice-versa while calculating the big O. In the first question we had `n` as a number of elements in array and `constant` as the number of checks so it turned to the `O(3n)=>O(n)`.

In the second case we have `constant` as the number of elements and the number of arrays equal to `n` so the calculation will following => `O(n * 10)=>O(n)`.

In the end we have absolute the same value of `O(n)` since it does not matter you have `3` arrays of `n` elements or `n` arrays of 3 elements, but only in case if you do not consider comparison. Comparison make the total complexity to multiply to the `log(number of arrays)` since it is minimum number of steps to compare everything.

In the first case the `log(const)` is negligible, in the second case the number of arrays is `n`, so we come to the `nlog(n)` complexity.

So this is the point of this task.